# Return Error if query returns no results

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling

I am creating a SQL job using the OPENROWSET function to export data from a view to excel.

I was just wondering if there was a way to have a the query return an error if there is are no rows of data returned, even though the query itself is executing correctly.

What i am looking for is a way where if the query below were to return 0 rows of data, the execution would return an "Error" result.  Whereas if it returned 1 or more rows of data, it would execute normally.

CustSalesBreakdown is a view i have created, which brings in sales by customer, grouping it by month/year.  As "Total" is a decimal value, I cast it as float for sorting it accordingly.

```
INSERT INTO OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
                   'Excel 8.0;Database=E:\Reports\CustSalesBreakdownTest.xls;', 
                   'SELECT * FROM [Test$]')
SELECT 
[Account],[Ref#],[CustomerName],[Phone],[Rep],[Period-MTD]
,[Invoices],[Credits],[Total],[FilterDate]

from custsalesbreakdown
where datediff(month,[FilterDate],getdate())=0 and [Rep] = '18'
order by cast([Total] as float) Desc;
```

This query executes successfully, however it returns no data, due to there being no data to return at that time.

The reason for this is that if it returns no rows of data, i want the job to proceed to a different step (On failure - Go to Step X), otherwise if it had returned values (On Success - Go to Step Y).

SamC

Comment: Can you be more specific? Can you use a UNION on the SELECT?

Comment: The select listed for the view chooses which columns to export to the Excel Spreadsheet, as not all the columns on the view are being exported.  The query itself runs perfectly.  I am just wondering if there is simple way to have the job itself deal with any cases where no data is present, by having the query fail.

Answer (score 2):

Dividing by zero always throws an error.

```
select 1/count(*) from table where column = 'something'
```